# Automatically checking checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have 3-level nested repeater as shown in the code.

Second (`RpMenu`) repeater has checkboxes that should check all checkboxes in the third one (`RbItems`).

How do I do this with JQuery?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RpGroups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RpGroups_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="GID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("groupid")%>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
        <div class="panel  panel-primary ">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<%# Eval("groupid")%>">
                <div class="panel-heading">

                    <h3 class="panel-title"><%# Eval("groupName")%>   </h3>


                </div>

            </a>
            <div class="panel-body ">
                <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="<%# Eval("groupid")%>">

                    <asp:Repeater ID="RpMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="FillMenuItems">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="panel panel-red">
                                <div class="panel-heading">

                                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center"><%# Eval("HeadItemText")%>
                                        <div class="navbar-right"></div>
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                    <table class="table table-striped ">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr class="alert-danger">
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th class="col-sm-2 control-label">Page Name</th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Full Add" runat="server" onclick="checkadd()" />Full Add</th>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    function checkadd() {
                                                        if (document.getElementById('Checkbox1').checked) {


                                                        }
                                                        else {

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                </script>
                                                <th>
                                                    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="Full View" onclick="checkview()" />Full View</th>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    function checkview() {
                                                        if (document.getElementById('Checkbox2').checked) {


                                                        }
                                                        else {

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                </script>
                                                <th>
                                                    <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" value="Full Updte" onclick="checkupdat()" />Full Updte</th>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    function checkupdat() {
                                                        if (document.getElementById('Checkbox3').checked) {


                                                        }
                                                        else {

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                </script>
                                                <th>
                                                    <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" value="Full Delete" onclick="checkdelet()" />Full Delete</th>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    function checkdelet() {
                                                        if (document.getElementById('Checkbox4').checked) {


                                                        }
                                                        else {

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                </script>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </table>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="RbItems" runat="server">

                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">


                                                    <tr class="view">
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="PID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tblMenuItemID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>
                                                        <td class="col-sm-2 control-label"><strong>
                                                            <div><%# Eval("MenuItemName")%></div>
                                                        </strong></td>


                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Update" /></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" /></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <%-- <li>
                                                <a href="<%# Eval("MenuItemLink")%>"><%# Eval("MenuItemName")%></a>
                                            </li>--%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>




        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I need to make it that when I check 'Checkbox1', all the checkboxes in repeater 3 with the name 'Add' are checked.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: 1 check box in second repeater check all check boxes in third repeater with defined name 'Add' Example

Comment: Post you jQuery code so we can see what you did so far. And you should try to make a smallest possible use case and post it here. Most of the code you posted is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: i need the jquery code bro i have methods with name chkdelete() for example i i can detect when the check box checked but i missed how to check other checkboxes (3'd repeater )

Comment: So you want us to do your work? :)

Comment: i need something like  
foreach (checkbox chk in repeater3)
{if (chk.name="add")
{
 chk.checked=true
}

Comment: my work ? no bro i want help catch the right way !